# I want to make this sentence into links

Tags: javascript, html

i have try this one `

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myString = "zero , one , two , three , four";

var mySplitResult = myString.split(" , ");

for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
    document.write("<a href=''>"+mySplitResult[i]+"</a>"); 
}
</script>
```

result  `<a href="zeroonetwothreefour">zeroonetwothreefour</a>` this link

but i want zero one two three four all with different like
ex- `<a href="zero">zero</a>`

Comment: oh sry got the ans `<script type="text/javascript">
var myString = "zero , one , two , three , four";

var mySplitResult = myString.split(" , ");

for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
 document.write("<a href='"+mySplitResult[i]+"'>"+mySplitResult[i]+"</a><br/>"); 
}
</script>` can you make it better some how?

Comment: There's a delete link in the menu under your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All links are different itself but you are not adding break line in between them

```js
var myString = "zero , one , two , three , four";

var mySplitResult = myString.split(" , ");

for(i = 0; i < mySplitResult.length; i++){
    document.write("<a href=''>"+mySplitResult[i]+"</a><br>");
}
```